# Move Web Directory to Raid Array

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, raid

I want to improve the performance of a web application running on Apache, so I created a Raid Array on /dev/md0.

Now I need to figure out how to move the application to the array and make sure that Apache will still serve it when someone accesses my domain.

> Web application is in the directory: /var/www/html - Raid Array device
>   is: /dev/md0

How do I make the application run on the array?

Cross Posted at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21713/move-web-directory-to-raid-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy all of your files to the new device, stop apache, then mount the new device on top of your existing /var/www/html and restart apache.

```
mount /dev/md0 /mnt
cp -r /var/www/html/* /mnt 
umount /mnt
service httpd stop
mount /dev/md0 /var/www/html
service httpd start
```

You would then need to ensure it's mounted at boot by editing the /etc/fstab

```
/dev/md0    /var/www/html ....
```

Comment: Also, make a filesystem on `md0` if there isn't already.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the contents of /var/www/html (or /var/www or all of /var if you want) to /dev/md0 and just mount /dev/md0 as /var/www/html (or whatever). Shouldn't be too complicated.